# Settings -> Printers showing no window at home but does at work

Tags: settings

I have recently installed Elementary OS Loki on my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T450s), and I have two similar network printers at work and at home (Xerox Workcentre 6605 and 6506). At work I use a wired connection with predefined IP, but at home we have DHCP.

Printer configuration at work went nicely, but at home there is no `Printers` window. If I run the switchboard from the command line it get the following four messages:

```
[INFO 22:29:37.111585] Application.vala:155: System Settings version: 2.0
[INFO 22:29:37.111620] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-64-generic

** (process:20056): CRITICAL **: string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

** (process:20056): CRITICAL **: string_contains: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
**
```

Then, if I choose `Printers`, I get the following two error messages:

```
ERROR:arraylist.c:957:gee_array_list_real_get: assertion failed: (index < _size)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas?

Regards,
Rafael